# Find out which activity started my activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to find out which activity started my activity in android. I can get the intent that started the activity using `getIntent()` but I am not able to find out which activity started the intent in the first place.

Comment: i think you have to put extra string in intent in everywhere from where you are opening your activity and in this extra string you can pass your activity name and in the activity in which you are getting extras from intent you can check this extra string and can determine which intent stated your activity.

Answer (score 30):

Use [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29)()

**Note**: if the calling activity is not expecting a result (that is it did not use the `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` form that includes a request code), then the calling package will be null

Comment: This would work if the current activity was stated using startActivityForResult(Intent, int), otherwise it would return null

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ActivityCompat.getReferrer()` for this purpose.

Comment: This also works for activities started through an Intent from another application

Comment: Can not find the AppCompat class, but find a similar method  ActivityCompat.getReferrer()

Comment: Returned uri contains the package name (not activity) that started the activity. Also, it can be spoofed.