# How to detect if my app is called by another

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two entrnces to my app: from menu and using Intent.
In the second case I need to return some EXTRA_OUTPUT by

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntentWithData)
finish()
```

so I need to detect if my app was called by another(finish in that case or continue work otherwise)

Comment: Use a distinct action string or something else on the `Intent` to distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

If your activity was called using `startActivityForResult()`, you can use `getCallingActivity()` method in your `Activity`. It will return a `ComponentName` of the activity that started yours (or **null** if your activity wasn't started with `startActivityForResult()` method). Then you can get `getCallingActivity().getPackageName()` or `getCallingActivity().getClassName()`.

More info here [getCallingActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getCallingActivity%28%29), https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336612/3569545

Answer (score 0):

Use [getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) method to get the intent that was the reason to start your activity.

Then if it was launched from the apps menu the intent will have action MAIN.

```
val intent = getIntent();

if (intent.getAction() != "android.intent.action.MAIN") {
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntentWithData)
   finish()
}
```

Comment: getLaunchIntentForPackage() used by the other app may very well return an intent with "android.intent.action.MAIN" set as the action so this may not work as expected.